# Docker compose pull settings.json from another location

Tags: docker-compose, nas, portainer

I'm pretty new to docker compose and I'm trying to figure out how to pull a settings file. I found some information but it's not correct so I commented it out.

Here is my .yaml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
transmission-openvpn:
    cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
        - '/volume1/data/:/data'
        - '/volume1/docker/transmission-openvpn/:/config'

    environment:
        - OPENVPN_PROVIDER=WINDSCRIBE
        - OPENVPN_CONFIG=Seattle...
        - OPENVPN_USERNAME=something
        - OPENVPN_PASSWORD=something
        - LOCAL_NETWORK=192.168.0.0/24
        - TRANSMISSION_WEB_UI=transmission-web-control
        #- type: bind
        #  source: /volume1/docker/transmission_settings.json
        #  target: /volume1/docker/transmission-openvpn/transmission-home/settings.json
    logging:
        driver: json-file
        options:
            max-size: 10m
    ports:
        - '9091:9091'
    image: haugene/transmission-openvpn
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to add an entry into the volumes

```
- '/volume1/docker/transmission_settings.json:/volume1/docker/transmission-openvpn/transmission-home/settings.json
```